# Absolute Positioning Relative to the Parent

Tags: jquery, height, absolute, css

My assumption was when using absolute positioning, that it was relative to the parent div. However, this jsfiddle doesn't seem to mesh with that. What I'm attempting to do is have a three row liquid layout with a min-height set on the center row. The top and bottom have a fixed height. Unfortunately, I am coding only for IE7 and don't have the luxury of using min-height in my CSS. When using JQuery, the center does resize, however, the footer does not reposition relative to the parent. Information and jsfiddle below.

Browser: IE7

Styling: CSS

HTML: 4.0 Strict

JQuery: 1.10.1

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wQAmA/)

fiddle after adding position:relative and height 100% to wrapper [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wQAmA/1/)

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="center"></div>
    <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper{
    background-color:blue;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    min-width:700px;
}
#top{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    min-width:700px;
    background-color:green;
}
#center{
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    bottom:20px;
    min-width:700px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:yellow;
}
#bottom{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    min-width:700px;
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    background-color:purple;
}
```

JQuery

```
var resizeTimer = false;
        function doResize() {
            if ($("body").height() == 500) {
                //do nothing
            }
            else if ($("body").height() < 500) {
                $("#wrapper").height(500);
                $("#center").height(380);

            }
            else {
                $("#wrapper").height("auto");
                $("#center").height("auto");
            }
            resizeTimer = false;
        }

        $(window).on("resize", function () {
            if (resizeTimer) {
                clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
            }
            resizeTimer = setTimeout(doResize, 300);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute positioning is relative the closest parent (going up the parent chain) that has position set on it (like `position: relative` or `position: absolute`).  If no parents in the parent chain have positioning set, then absolute positioning is relative to the document boundaries.

If you want `position: absolute` to be relative to the parent, the set `position: relative` on the parent.  That will not change the position of the parent, but will scope the positioning of the children to be relative to the parent rather than relative to some higher level parent or document.

Comment: that causes and odd disappearing act for my divs on resize. See new jsfiddle.

Comment: Scratch that. Needed a 100% in the jquery as opposed to auto. See js fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/wQAmA/1/. You get the accept since you were first. Thanks!

Comment: I also noticed that positioning breaks if parent has `display: inline`. Use `display: block` for parent to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

The position is not relative to the parent, it's relative to the closest parent that has positioning (or the document, if no parent has positioning).

Add `position:relative` to the CSS for the parent element to make it have positioning without actually moving it anywhere.

Comment: That causes a strange disappearing act for my divs on resize. see new jsfiddle

Comment: Scratch that. Needed a 100% in the jquery as opposed to auto. See js fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/wQAmA/1/.